# how can I find the Side length Two squares inside an equilateral Triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

> **Question: Figure shows an equilateral triangle with side length equal to  $1$ . Two squares of side length  a  and $2a$  placed side by side just fit inside the triangle as shown.**
>
> **Find the exact value of  $a$.**

Its an Assessment question from edX course "A-Level Mathematics Course 1"  and I am supposed to use skills that I learnt in **Indices and surds,Inequalities and The Factor Theorem**.

I have tried finding the height of triangle and then use similar triangles to find the right triangle length still No luck.

I am just looking for food for thought or very small hints thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* You have everything you need along the base. Also, note the two flanking right triangles.

Comment: i think i got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the leftmost right triangle,
$$
\frac{a}{x} = \tan(60°) \implies a = \sqrt{3}x
$$
From the rightmost right triangle
$$
\frac{2a}{1-3a-x} = \frac{a}{x} \\
a = \frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{6} \approx 0.211
$$

Comment: I think you are on the right path to an answer, but there is not enough detail. First, you should typeset your answer with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Second, give more details. E.g. what is $x$?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this too. But the info is along the bottom. The triangle is equilateral so all angles are $60°$. On the left there is a right-angled triangle - let's call its base $x$.

Triangle 1: Angle = $60°$, opposite = $a$, and adjacent = $x$

On the right there is another right-angled triangle and its base is $1-3a-x$.

Triangle 2: Angle = $60°$, opposite = $2a$, and adjacent = $1 - 3a - x$

From triangle 1:
$$\tan60° = \frac{a}{x} \implies x = \frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$$

From triangle 2:
$$\tan60° = \frac{2a}{1-3a-x}$$

Equalising $\tan60°$ and substituting for $x$:

$$\frac{2a}{1-3a-x} = \frac{a}{x} \implies \frac{2a}{1-3a-\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}} = \frac{a}{\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}}$$

Simplify:

$$\frac{2}{1-3a-\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{a}$$

$$\frac{2a}{1-3a-\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}} = \sqrt{3}$$

$$2a = \sqrt{3}(1-3a-\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}})$$

$$3a +3a\sqrt{3}= \sqrt{3}$$

$$a= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{(3 +3\sqrt{3})}$$
Rationalise the Denominator

$$a= \frac{\sqrt{3}(3 -3\sqrt{3})}{(3 +3\sqrt{3})(3 -3\sqrt{3})}$$

$$a= \frac{3 -\sqrt{3}}{6}$$