# Find $a$ by looking at the triangle containing squares.

Tags: geometry

Figure 1 shows an equilateral triangle with side length equal to  $1$. Two squares of side length  $a$  and  $2a$  placed side by side just fit inside the triangle as shown.

[image]

Comment: Find the value of the side a, of the square that is inside the triangle.

Comment: There is a $30-60-90$ triangle at both sides of the squares, can you calculate the length of their bases?

Comment: This question has been asked before: [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360970/how-can-i-find-the-side-length-two-squares-inside-an-equilateral-triangle)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Calculate lengths along the base of the equilateral triangle.

Comment: I've been trying however I am not able to find out the value of 1-3a.

Comment: @DiegoMoreno There is a $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle on the left. Do you know the side lengths?

Answer (score 0):

The two triangles at the ends of the base represent half of equilateral triangles, respectively of height $\,a\,$ and $\,2a$. So the length of the base can be described as follows:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt 3}+a+2a+\frac{2a}{\sqrt 3}=1$$
$$a(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})+2a(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})=1$$
$$3a(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})=1$$
Finally:
$$a=\frac{1}{3+\sqrt 3}$$